# Inspect Android Browser elements like Desktop Chrome Inspector

Tags: browser, usb-debugging, stock-browser

I'm a web developer (don't know any native Android Development) and would like to inspect any web page in Android's browser without using an emulator.   Is there something available like how you can plug an iPhone into a Mac and use Safari to inspect the page just as if it were a webpage being loaded in the desktop Safari browser?

If this is not available, what is the next best thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with the old "Android browser", but you can in Chrome, which is downloadable from Google Play and comes installed on all recent Android devices. The feature you're looking for is called *Chrome Remote Debugging*, and it relies on having Chrome on your desktop and ADB enabled and connected.

Comment: Good to know.  Unfortunately I need to have some live debugging on a Android stock browser only.  It's not horizontally scrolling something that works fine on all other mobile browsers I can test on. What's the next best thing?